# I want to know something about this code

Tags: c

can anyone help me to explain me this code why the result of this code is "1 1 3"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    static int a[]={1,3,2,3,4};
    int *p[]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
    int **ptr=p;
    ptr++;
    printf("\n%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apart from anything else, "%d" is the wrong format specifier for a pointer.

Comment: @MartinJames `ptr-p` and `*ptr-a` are a difference (as integer), not a pointer. Also `**ptr` is `int`.

Comment: The author of this code should be locked away from any computer.

Comment: i am sorry the result is "1 1 3" , i just need the explanation of this code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. we cannot sanction profs/TA's in such a manner.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you're right.  I had stars in my eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look up "pointer arithmetic" if you want to know more and/or my answer will not help.

**Explanation:**

`int *p[]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};` fills the array `p` with pointers to each element in array `a`. It is equivalent to `int *p[]={&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3],&a[4]}`. `p[0]` points to `a[0]`, `p[1]` points to `a[1]` and so on.

`int **ptr=p;` then creates pointer that points at beginning of array `p`. That is, it is equivalent to `int **ptr=&p[0];`.

`ptr++` increments `ptr`, so that it points to next element. In this case, result is same as `ptr = &p[1];`.

Then, when printing numbers:

subtracting pointers (pointer arithmetic) means that result is equal to number of elements that can fit between two operands. Because you incremented ptr line before, they are exactly 1 element apart (that is, `sizeof(int *)`). `ptr` points to `p[1]`, and `p` points to `p[0]`.

Same goes for `*ptr - a`, they are 1 element apart (only in this case, it is `sizeof(int)`). `*ptr` (that is, `p[1]`) points to `a[1]`, `a` points to `a[0]`.

And `ptr` points to `p[1]`, which points to `a[1]`, which is `3`, therefore `**ptr` is `3`.

**Code warnings:**

As pointed out by David Bowling, the `printf` statement uses the wrong format specifiers for the provided arguments. As result of pointer subtraction, for example `ptr-p`, is of type `ptrdiff_t`, correct format specifier is `%td`: `printf("\n%td %td %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);`

Using `%d` specifier is used with `int` type and causes undefined behavior when used with incorrect types.

You can see what specifiers to use with which types for example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: A good explanation of the pointer arithmetic, yet the posted code generates warnings and has undefined behavior due to a mismatch between format specifiers and arguments: `ptr - p` and `*ptr - a` have type `ptrdiff_t`. The correct `printf()` format specifier is `%td`: `printf("\n%td %td %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);`.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks for pointing out. I wasn't really sure of that expression's result type, and didn't bother to assure myself whether it is actually `int` (as i first expected). However, I assume that `ptrdiff_t` will be mostly same as `int` on today's usual platforms.

Comment: Actually, `ptrdiff_t` is likely to be a `typedef` of `long int`. `t` is a length modifier that can be used with `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, or `n`. The warning on my system is: _warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]_.

Comment: @DavidBowling: on 64-bit windows system, it is more likely `long long int` and `%td` might not be supported. Given the values in this lame example, `printf("\n%d %d %d\n",(int)(ptr-p),(int)(*ptr-a),**ptr);` is a simpler workable version.

Comment: @chqrlie-- I did not realize that `long long` was common in 64-bit Windows systems here. As for `%td`, I was of course referring to _compliant_ compilers ;) Good advice I saw once for such values when, e.g., `%td` is not available: cast to the widest possible signed type and use the appropriate conversion specifier for that type; yet not really an issue with the posted code....